# How do I use “separate" keyword

Tags: ada

I am unable to figure out keyword `separate` in Ada and its depth concept. Please help me to understand by giving a small example?

Lets say I have a nested procedure

```ada
with ada.text_io; use ada.text_io;
procedure main is
   procedure proc is
   begin
      put_line ("i am proc");
   end proc;
begin
   put_line ("main");
end main;
```

How to use separate keyword ?

Comment: What do you mean by “depth concept”?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You primarily use the separate keyword to achieve one of 2 effects.

1. OS specific actions. (Put 2 versions of the procedure / functions in different directories, and compile for 2 different targets)
2. Separation of a lengthy procedure from surrounding code.

Here is an example to show the syntax.

package_x.ads

```
package Package_X is

   procedure Foo;
   procedure Sep;

end Package_X;
```

package_x.adb

```
package body Package_X is

   procedure Foo is 
   begin
      null;
   end Foo;

   procedure Sep is separate;

end Package_X;
```

package_x-sep.adb

```
separate (Package_X) procedure Sep is 
begin
   null;
end Sep;
```

Comment: i m getting error as cannot generate code for file  package_x.adb(missing subunits)?

Comment: Is package_x-sep.adb visible to your compiler?  (Is it created, in its search path etc ?)

Comment: yes it is created can u please show me how you are calling the procedure ?

Comment: You call it in the same as any other procedure!

Answer (score 2):

The *separate* keyword creates a unit of compilation, a subunit, that is compiled independently.  The parameter of *separate* refers to the package in which the subunit is a sub unit of.

So if you had a package body X, then you remove procedure Y from it, you create a sub unit of X by creating a new file in which you place Y, and put "separate(X)" at the start of the file, to indicate that Y is really part of X.

Comment: With GNAT, the `separate` body isn’t compiled separately in the sense of producing object code. You can do a separate syntactic check (`-gnats`) or a semantic check (`-gnatc`), though.